# What kind of filtering does this op-amp perform?

Tags: operational-amplifier, sensor, filter, active-filter

I am using a heart rate sensor whose schematic is provided [here](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Biometric/PulseSensorAmpd%20-%20Schematic.pdf). The circuit uses an operational amplifier (towards the right of the figure) which among other things, does a filtering operation. I would like to get a hint on what kind of filter configuration this is. Specifically, I am interested in the following:

1- Is this an active low pass filter, high pass filter or both?

2- What is the frequency range of this circuit? In other words, what are the cutoff frequencies of these filters.

If someone can provide any relevant hints, that would be great. I would also appreciate if somebody can be point me to relevant resources on this.

The [APDS-9008](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optical-sensors/ambient-light-photo-sensors/apds-9008) is a Broadcom package that is a photo sensitive LED with a unity voltage follower and the [MCP6001](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/21733h-26779.pdf) is a low powered, 1 MHz op amp. Lastly, the 0603 is a Schottky Diode.

[image]

Comment: The signal conditioner ought to match the bandwidth spectrum of the signal.  YOu can use Falstad's simultor to sketch the circuit with An OpAmp and trace the result with a log swept sine input or a step response. Or your favorite tool.  THis is something you must learn.

Comment: It's clearly a bandpass of some sort and the interesting frequencies are clearly in the ballpark of kilohertz, but it's beyond my skills to analyse it more throughly than that.

Comment: Also are you sure the sensor has a voltage follower, the datasheet is crap but it talks about output currents rather than output voltages.

Answer (score 1):

The signal conditioner ought to match the bandwidth spectrum of the signal. You can use Falstad's simultor to sketch the circuit with an OpAmp and trace the result with a log swept sine input.  Due to limitations in this AC analyzer for low freq=1Hz, I scaled all frequencies up 3 decades by reducing  all C's down the same.

As expected it matches the spectrum of a heartbeat at 120BPM or 2 Hz.  In theory , if my assumption is  true, this is called a "matched filter" the optimum for signal conditioning to max SNR.

[image]

With lots of practice, this took me 10 minutes, and another 10 to edit the screen shot and make it pretty.

[**Here's a built-in filter**](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%203%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%2028853.998118144256%0Aw%20264%20128%20248%20128%200%0Aw%20200%2064%20200%20128%200%0Aw%20304%20136%20304%20128%200%0Aw%20304%20128%20304%2064%200%0AO%20456%20128%20504%20128%200%0A170%20152%20128%20120%20128%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0AB%20152%2032%20304%20312%201%20Box%0Ac%20200%20128%20248%20128%200%206.499816291014687e-8%200%0Ac%20200%2064%20248%2064%200%201.0000000000000002e-7%200%0Ar%20248%2064%20248%20128%200%204576.300836108813%0Aw%20248%2064%20304%2064%200%0Ar%20152%20128%20200%20128%200%20845.7021465740045%0Ar%20200%20128%20200%20216%200%20363.52288574362404%0Ag%20200%20216%20200%20232%200%0Aa%20264%20136%20304%20136%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20264%20144%20264%20232%200%0AB%20304%2032%20456%20312%201%20Box%0Aw%20416%20128%20400%20128%200%0Aw%20352%2064%20352%20128%200%0Aw%20456%20136%20456%20128%200%0Aw%20456%20128%20456%2064%200%0Ac%20352%20128%20400%20128%200%206.499816291014647e-8%200%0Ac%20352%2064%20400%2064%200%201.0000000000000002e-7%200%0Ar%20400%2064%20400%20128%200%207603.277775235189%0Aw%20400%2064%20456%2064%200%0Ar%20304%20128%20352%20128%200%202995.179332723603%0Ar%20352%20128%20352%20216%200%20491.75566694001736%0Ag%20352%20216%20352%20232%200%0Aa%20416%20136%20456%20136%202%2015%20-15%201000000%0Ag%20416%20144%20416%20232%200%0A)

Comment: A simple bandpass in this case. A [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) has a more complicated kernel, a bit more than what a simple opamp+RC can handle.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen  **Nope.**  A Matched Filter is exactly as I defined.  The theory for complex brick wall filters is also true but does not exclude the fundamental. requirement to match the spectrum and  the phase

Comment: It's a compromise of the signal spectra because BPM changes. Of course, I have seen the Fourier spectra of heartbeats and recall its shape. is an approximation.

Comment: Are you saying that the wikipedia page is wrong? Or that this is, indeed, a matched filter?