# Can the direct current output of a photodiode pass through a capacitor? If so what effect are they having in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, photodiode

I am studying RC filtering in order to try and understand this circuit which was previously discussed in([What kind of filtering does this op-amp perform?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/396567/what-kind-of-filtering-does-this-op-amp-perform)).

The answers gave advice on testing the response to a sine wave sweep which should show it's filtering of undesired noise/interference such as mains electricity at 50/60Hz. I want to follow the path/modifications to the signal itself which to my knowledge is a direct current produced by the photodiode. Can this current pass through the capacitors and if so how?

I am trying to identify sub-components of the circuit and learn what effects they are having, please correct any misunderstanding:

1.The two 100K resistors are there to introduce an offset voltage so as to center the Op-Amp output at 2.5V? They do not have any additional effects?

2.The feedback path from Vout through two series resistors R6 (feedback resistor)& R5 forms another voltage divider. The fact that R6 is far far larger means only a very small voltage difference will be seen at VIn-.

3.Lastly, the feedback branch R5 and C4 appears to me to be a differentiator but I am unsure how to test this in simulation as I am interested in how the circuit processes the signal of interest - a varying direct current, rather than the AC noise of a sweep signal.

Any advice or input appreciated.

[image: Circuit for amplifying & filtering input from a photodiode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can DC go thru a Capacitor?  NO

Is it DC that the Light Sensor picks up from the pulsing LED going thru a finger?  NO

**What might it look like?**

Time domain and Freq. Domain with 0 to 100 Hz linear bins.

[image]

This is my hand-drawn image of a heartbeat at 120 BPM with log dB vs linear Fourier spectrum to 100Hz.

**What is the circuit?**

First Caps reduce the voltage in half but also act as passive LPF followed by a Sallen-Key BandPass Filter (BPF) . The upward slope amplifies the downward slope of the spectrum of the heartbeat.

You can say it is basically a band-limited active differentiator.  The heart signal is differentiated and higher f noise is attenuated. [image]

The output would amplify the middle pulse of the QRST wave.

Comment: Stewart I have tried to brush up on filtering concepts and get accustomed to circuit simulators but have not been able to generate the real circuit in KiCad etc and LTSpice is unavailable in Linux. I have been trying to build my intuition using the Lush/Falstad simulator but when I build the circuit as shown in your post I cannot make any sense of the output. For a composite sinusoid which resembles the expected input of a PPG quite well; the output is a square wave. Really quite stumped by this, I would have expected to observe the bandpass effects when I change the frequency.

Comment: The effects of reducing the capacitance and increasing the input frequency by the same factor fully cancel out correct? So this circuit should have maximal gain at 2*10^3 Hz? I cannot seem to get an output that morphologically resembles the input regardless of the frequency. One last question, why would the voltage be halved (by the action of C3 & C4) only for an offset to be introduced later?

Comment: No 3 decades down or 2Hz , I used nF rather than uF to get 2kHz for convenience. I have no idea why they did except to meet some specs on shape. Remember ideal SNR matches the spectrum of all the signals.     It is obvious to me how it works so here is a simplified version for you.  https://tinyurl.com/yj7bqckl. The cap divider serves no purpose.

Comment: The simplified version is NOT the same but has a similar shape for your intuitive understanding. It is basically a dominant HPF with LPF  https://tinyurl.com/ydnytofb to make an asymmetric wide BPF

Comment: You are not trying to produce a square wave or triangle but a spectral density of sine waves. A muscle wave and heart waves have a different frequency spectral density  peak yet as I pointed out a similar shape in spectrum. Yet a different time domain shape.

Comment: The spectral density will have something to with the source and the axon medium.

Comment: Just to clarify; the original circuit I posted has maximal gain at 2Hz; your simulated version 2kHz? From the interactive plot where I can sweep through the frequencies; this seems to say that starting at just above 0Hz the phase shift is -90 with attenutation (-dB). The attenuation changes to amplification as we move towards 2kHz while the phase shift goes to -180. But then at 4kHz the phase shift swaps to +180 and again amplification decays for higher frequencies? Is there any tool to convert this circuit to a digital filter to see what it does to a real life input?

Comment: THe same tools I used can simulate in the time domain, or frequency domain on different pages but the .../afilter cannot display below 10 Hz well so I shifted the spectrum up 3 decades. It does not change the shape in time or frequency, so use 2kHz and think 2 Hz.. You can simulate any frequency on Falstad by changing the time domain sampling rate under options  even rediculous frequencies like 1 uHz or 100 THz  but the frequency domain start is fixed and upper end slider is too high for you. In time domain you can even record audio and import the wave, yet not tried.  and display spectrum

Comment: Falstad's sims do everything you need. after learning curve